# How to know animation type in VBA

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I want to know what animation type is in each shape that I found in a presentation. I am using the following lines for that:

```
 'to know if the shape has animation 
 If ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).Shapes(shapeNum).AnimationSettings.Animate = msoTrue Then
    animationType = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).Shapes(shapeNum).AnimationSettings.EntryEffect
```

With there in some cases I can different answers like ppEffectFlyFromLeft or ppEffectFlyFromRight but for example for Fade and Zoom animation type the result is ppEffectCut and I cannot find any other variable that says me what kind of animation is. Where can I find the variable that gives me that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the animation type here:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).TimeLine.MainSequence(shapeAniNum).EffectType
```

Hope it will help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
Sub GetEntryEffectFromSlide()

      Dim sSlideObject As Slide
      Dim lTypeOfEffect As Long

      ' Get the slide show transition EntryEffect property for the slide.
      For Each sSlideObject In ActivePresentation.Slides
         lTypeOfEffect = sSlideObject.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect
      Next sSlideObject

End Sub
```

You can use the following constants with the EntryEffect property.

```
Appear:
ppEffectAppear
Fly Effects:
ppEffectFlyFromBottom
ppEffectFlyFromBottomLeft
ppEffectFlyFromBottomRight
ppEffectFlyFromLeft
ppEffectFlyFromRight
ppEffectFlyFromTop
ppEffectFlyFromTopLeft
ppEffectFlyFromTopRight
Blinds Effects:
ppEffectBlindsHorizontal
ppEffectBlindsVertical
Box Effects:
ppEffectBoxInm
ppEffectBoxOut
Checkerboard Effects:
ppEffectCheckerboardAcross
pEffectCheckerboardDown
Crawl Effects:
ppEffectCrawlFromDown
ppEffectCrawlFromLeft
ppEffectCrawlFromRight
ppEffectCrawlFromUp
Dissolve:
ppEffectDissolve
Flash Effects:
ppEffectFlashOnceFast
ppEffectFlashOnceMedium
ppEffectFlashOnceSlow
Peek Effects:
ppEffectPeekFromDown
ppEffectPeekFromLeft
ppEffectPeekFromRight
ppEffectPeekFromUp
Random Effects:
ppEffectRandomBarsHorizontal
ppEffectRandomBarsVertical
ppEffectRandom
Spiral:
ppEffectSpiral
Split Effects:
ppEffectSplitHorizontalIn
ppEffectSplitHorizontalOut
ppEffectSplitVerticalIn
ppEffectSplitVerticalOut
Stretch Effects:
ppEffectStretchAcross
ppEffectStretchDown
ppEffectStretchLeft
ppEffectStretchRight
ppEffectStretchUp
Strips Effects:
ppEffectStripsDownLeft
ppEffectStripsDownRight
ppEffectStripsLeftDown
ppEffectStripsLeftUp
ppEffectStripsRightDown
ppEffectStripsRightUp
ppEffectStripsUpLeft
ppEffectStripsUpRight
Swivel:
ppEffectSwivel
Wipe Effects:
ppEffectWipeDown
ppEffectWipeLeft
ppEffectWipeRight
ppEffectWipeUp
Zoom Effects:
ppEffectZoomBottom
ppEffectZoomCenter
ppEffectZoomIn
ppEffectZoomInSlightly
ppEffectZoomOut
ppEffectZoomOutSlightly
Uncover Effects:
ppEffectUncoverDown
ppEffectUncoverLeft
ppEffectUncoverLeftDown
ppEffectUncoverLeftUp
ppEffectUncoverRight
ppEffectUncoverRightDown
ppEffectUncoverRightUp
ppEffectUncoverUp
Cover Effects:
ppEffectCoverDown
ppEffectCoverLeft
ppEffectCoverLeftDown
ppEffectCoverLeftUp
ppEffectCoverRight
ppEffectCoverRightDown
ppEffectCoverRightUp
ppEffectCoverUp
Cut Effects:
ppEffectCut ppEffectCutThroughBlack
Fade:
ppEffectFade
No Effect:
ppEffectNone
Mixed:
ppEffectMixed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need it for shapes not for slides. I check it and the result is ppEffectNone and in the shape it puts ppEffectFlyFromLeft. I thinks that you misunderstood my question. I need to see the effect that a shape have but for example in zoom animation and in fade animation the result is in both ppEffectCut and I need to difference them. It will also be great to know where is the value of the duration of the animation. Thanks